# What's the right phonetic transcription of the word man?

Tags: phonetics, phonemes, sociolinguistics

Is it [mɛən] or [mæən] ?

I've seen both of them in some videos; however, I'm not really sure Which one of them truly represents the sound (with the æ raising).

Comment: Definitely not the second because that would mean it has a phonemic diphthong, which it doesn't in all the dialects I know of.

Comment: Well, diphthongization is pretty well attested for US dialects.

Comment: This is a pair that's involved in the US Northern Cities shift. Location, gender, and socioeconomic status are important independent variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues here, one about the sounds themselves and two about the conventions of transcriptions. /mæn/ etc. implies either "underlying form" or "phonemic form", which are completely different things – the notation is used indiscriminately. The difference between underlying forms and phonemic forms is a technical distinction that you probably don't care about. [mæn] etc. says "this is how it is pronounced", which also *can* be the same as the phonemic form.

The issue about the sounds themselves is, who's talking? The vowel in "man" varies substantially, depending on dialect. Either [æ] or [ɛ] is reasonable. The second issue about conventions is that the cardinal vowel standard for how [ɛ] and [æ] are pronounced is, well, a dying art. The vowel usually written æ in English is not the same as either ɛ or æ as observed in the Jones-Ladefoged-Esling-Wells-House performances, and people typically select the "nearest vowel" from the defined set of vowels. People differ in their judgements of closeness.

All that said, the majority of people transcribe *man* as [mæn], then [mæən] is a distinct minority transcription. Writing [mɛən] is hardest to defend, since "men" is pronounced different (unless it isn't in that dialect), and without the use of diacritics, there is no reasonable distinct transcription of *men* possible if you think *man* is [mɛən]. Unless you transcribe *men* as [mɪən], which is how it sounds in some dialects. So you have to check the author's theory of transcription and the dialect they are talking about.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this and in a such good way! Since I've seen [mɛən] on wikipedia ( about the æ tensing)  I assumed that was the "correct" transcription.

Comment: In the UK, [a] or [ä] is quite common as a phonetic realisation (see e.g. the IPA illustrations for Tyneside and Liverpool English), though it is very often still transcribed as [æ], mainly for historical reasons it seems.

Comment: But it is not a diphthong in any British accent that I can think of.